# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference.IService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have Web Service and Windows Service Application, also i have added Web Service Reference in Windows Service Application, after that i have created the .exe file by building Windows Service Application. Using the installutil *.exe cmd i made this as services. But if i start my Service its shows the following error in log file:

> start service Another entry at 7/1/2015 8:00:45 AM Inside Export Data
>   Getting DB Connection C:\Temp\ Calling WebService... Exception...
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint
>   element that references contract
>   'ClosersCloudServiceReference.IClosersCloudService' in the
>   ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client
>   element.    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint
>   serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String
>   configurationName, Configuration configuration)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String
>   configurationName)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String
>   configurationName, EndpointAddress address)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String
>   endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1
>   endpointTrait)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()    at
>   ccExportWindowsService.ClosersCloudServiceReference.ClosersCloudServiceClient..ctor()
>   at ccExportWindowsService.ccExportService.OnElapsedTime(Object source,
>   ElapsedEventArgs e)

**NOTE:**  Its works fine Before Converting *.exe and calling WCF Service in development Environment.

Comment: What do you mean by "converting *.exe"?

Comment: If i build the Windows Service Application i will get the *.exe file the location bin/Debug/abc.exe. Then i need to add this application to OS Services, for that am using the command installutil abc.exe in "Open VS2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt". Now abc.exe runs in Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Services. If i start this service we got the above error.

Comment: The error is fairly clear.   Pleas post your service code and app.config's `<system.serviceModel>` section.